# running queries on more than one table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query in two tables:

- `SIMPLE_PERSON` with 3 fields (name, grid and Social Security Card)
- `INDIVIDUAL_AGGREGATE` with 4 fields: grid(PK), type( D(Driver) or C(client)), code, simple_person(foreign key of simple_person))

When I register some person, I have to save they on the `SIMPLE_PERSON` and set the type of aggregate that they are ( Driver or Client). And cannot have two equal social security card numbers.

With AJAX, I throw a checker that returns an alert box if the SSC is registered, but my SQL query doesn't work.  I need to making a query that returns to me if a Social Security Card is already registered. I'm trying to use EXISTS, but I haven't had much success:

```
SELECT simple_person.name 
  FROM simple_person 
 WHERE SSC = 'SSC_NUMBER' 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT individual_aggregate.code FROM individual_aggregate
                WHERE code = 'xx' 
                  AND individual_aggregate.type = 'D');
```

Somebody can help me to make this query work?

Comment: I pray to the gods of the internet that you are not actually storing SSN's in a database.

Comment: Why do you need the `EXISTS...` portion of the query? if you're looking to see that the SSC isn't already registered, couldn't you just do a `SELECT count(*) FROM simple_person WHERE SSC = 'SSC_NUMBER'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you wanted to check if there is a person that registered on a some Social security number?

if yes what i did is join between the two tables
and return the rows that equal to a specific social security number.

you can add to the WHERE statement (AND IA.code = 'XX' AND IA.Type = 'D')

```
SELECT SP.Name
FROM simple_person AS SP
INNER JOIN individual_aggregate AS IA ON SP.grid = IA.grid
WHERE SP.SSC = {someNumber}
```

helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery in the `EXISTS` clause isn't actually hitting a table, view or other.

Comment: Agreed, was going to log comment to check if that's a typo though

Answer (score 0):

Your sub-select is missing the FROM clause.

SELECT 
     individual_aggregate.code 
FROM 
     individual_aggregate
WHERE
     code = 'xx' 
AND  individual_aggregate.type = 'D'

Regards
   Sigersted